# How to show file size in MB on Windows XP?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, windows-explorer

It's strange that Windows XP is showing my file in KB in details view under Windows Explorer (there is a 14GB file in the folder, so it doesn't make sense). Is there a setting somewhere to change this? I remember Windows XP displays file size in MB so not sure why this computer is showing figures in KB.

Comment: Are you sure about this? According to http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-desktop/display-file-size-in-bytes-on-windows-explorer/729a2b3a-4414-431b-a639-8fabcc7c4862 it isn't the case

Answer (score 1):

According to Azeez Nadeem, a Microsoft support employee:

> This cannot be changed. Windows Explorer will display the size column in the smallest unit, “KB” for simplicity. If you select your file and view the details pane, you will see the file in its true form, whether it’s MB or GB.
>   There are third party programs that are able to do what you are asking [...]
>
> <sub>Source: [Display File Size in Bytes on Windows Explorer](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-desktop/display-file-size-in-bytes-on-windows-explorer/729a2b3a-4414-431b-a639-8fabcc7c4862)</sub>

You may try [Total Commander](http://www.ghisler.com/) or a similar file manager.

Comment: Hi, it appears that you copied this answer from [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-desktop/display-file-size-in-bytes-on-windows-explorer/729a2b3a-4414-431b-a639-8fabcc7c4862). I've edited the answer for you, but next time remember to give credit where credit is due.

Comment: Sorry my mistake